# Keeping the selected item of DropDownList during resetting DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have several `DropDownlist` controls in my web page which the `DataSource` of all of them set to a specified list of items.

When one of these items is selected from one of the `DropDownlist` ,this item should remove from the list of other `DropDownList`. So I should set the `DataSource` of all of `DropDownList` again.

But in this case the selected item returned to the first item.

Is there any way to keep the selected item of `DropDownList` during resetting `DataSource`?

**Edit:**

```
protected void dropdownlist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(dropdownlist1.Text))
         //Some code to remove the selected item from list so the user can not see it in the select list anymore

    dropdownlist1.DataSource = myList;
    dropdownlist1.DataBind();

    dropdownlist2.DataSource = myList;
    dropdownlist2.DataBind();

    dropdownlist3.DataSource = myList;
    dropdownlist3.DataBind();

    //...
}
```

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: I think that before changing stuff around, you can keep (for each DDL) the value of `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` and then after changing the what you need setting it back. I must say that having the same source for all DDL and manipulating it sounds a bad idea - I'd consider having a different list for each DDL. (why? if item `x` is chosen in DDL1, and you remove it from the list that is the `dataSource` for all DDLs, what are you going to see in DDL1?)

Comment: @shapiroyaacov, Thanks for your reply,but i can not keep the selected index of all ddls because i have about 100 ddls !!! And for your second suggestion, i have done this in windows application however i have problem in asp.net